# Convert Any type in scala to Array[Byte] and back

Tags: scala, serialization

I have a variable value declared as `Any` in my program.

I want to convert this value to `Array[Byte]`.

How can I serialize to `Array[Byte]` and back? I found examples related to other types such as `Double` or `Int`, but not to `Any`.

Comment: How can you serialize something when you don't know what it is?

Comment: I have the same question.. It is an input from a user, it can be image, number, string.. and then I need to convert it into Array[Byte] so I can store it to DB

Comment: If it is an input from the user, then it is already a `String`, isn't it? So why not just store the `String`?

Comment: As far as I know it is not a String, but it can be anything.. What you mean is to cast it as a string? It is a part of a project that I do not know. I only see an interface with parameters where there is a parameter type Any.

Comment: Assuming it is Serializable (a stream isn't, for instance), how do you deserialize it to a type you do not know ? Keeping an array of bytes is as good as it gets.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This should do what you need.  It's pretty similar to how one would do it in Java.

```
import java.io.{ByteArrayInputStream, ByteArrayOutputStream, ObjectInputStream, ObjectOutputStream}

object Serialization extends App {

  def serialise(value: Any): Array[Byte] = {
    val stream: ByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val oos = new ObjectOutputStream(stream)
    oos.writeObject(value)
    oos.close()
    stream.toByteArray
  }

  def deserialise(bytes: Array[Byte]): Any = {
    val ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes))
    val value = ois.readObject
    ois.close()
    value
  }

  println(deserialise(serialise("My Test")))
  println(deserialise(serialise(List(1))))
  println(deserialise(serialise(Map(1 -> 2))))
  println(deserialise(serialise(1)))
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much this works. I also found the following.. what is the difference with your solution?

Comment: Use `ois.close()`, etc. -- the bracketless notation should be reserved for methods that don't change state.

Comment: thanks Mohan, I've updated the answer to include your suggestion of "close()" since it's semantically better than "close" to highlight the side effect of closing the stream

Answer (score 3):

```
def anyTypeToByteArray(value: Any): Array[Byte] = {
    val valueConverted :Array[Byte] = SerializationUtils.serialize(value.isInstanceOf[Serializable])
    valueConverted
  }

  def ByteArrayToAny(value: Array[Byte]): Any = {
    val valueConverted: Any = SerializationUtils.deserialize(value)
    valueConverted
  }
```

Comment: Yours uses a third party library.

Comment: As JasperM mentioned, this uses Apache commons.  Also a viable solution if you are willing to bring it in.

Comment: `SerializationUtils.serialize(value.isInstanceOf[Serializable])` is wrong. The function does not take as input a Boolean.
it should be `SerializationUtils.serialize(value)`