# Storing Scala data structures on disk

Tags: scala, pickle, persistent

I am trying to store result of some computations which I have stored in memory in `HashMap` and a `List`. Is there a way to store and load these data structures on disk so that I don't have to repeat this process over and over again?

EDIT

1. I am looking for a standard library like `pickle` in `python` and not an external dependency.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Any type in scala to Array\[Byte\] and back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39369319/convert-any-type-in-scala-to-arraybyte-and-back)

Answer (score 3):

Both `List` and `HashMap` (as well as other collections) are [`Serializable`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Serializable.html) in Scala, which means that standard Java serialization mechanisms can be applied to them.

You can store the objects by creating an [`ObjectOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) and calling its `writeObject(obj)` method.

The same applies for reading objects through an [`ObjectInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) and its `readObject()` method.

The objects in the collections to read/write are also expected to be  `Serializable`, so if it's not yet the case, you'll need to make them implement the interface.

Comment: So the other data structures are not serializable?

Comment: The other data structures become serializable if they implement the `Serializable` interface/trait. Indeed, this is a marker interface and there is nothing to implement, just add it to the class declaration.