# How to ensure output dataframe is dynamically partitioned such that each partition is around 128mb?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In Spark, I have a few jobs chained (i.e. output of one will be input to the next). The issue I am facing is, say, my input dataset to first job is 10GB today and I am repartitioning it statically (hardcoded number, coalesce or repartition) before writing the output such that its around 128mb per partition. As the data grows, the hardcoded number obviously starts to make partitions bigger and in a few months downstream jobs starts to become slower due to the higher partition size.

One way I tried to ensure partitions are always around 128mb is by dividing the total dataset size (row count) by a static number. That is, if a dataset with 1M rows is 500mb, I estimate that approx 250k rows would be around 128mb. So number of partitions I would need is `df.count()/250,000`

That sort of works but is there a better/more straightforward way to accomplish this without affecting the performance of the job much?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62648621/spark-sql-files-maxpartitionbytes-not-limiting-max-size-of-written-partitions

Comment: @mck : Thank you for that! So what do we do when shuffle operations are involved?

Comment: what spark version are you using? in Spark 3, `spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.enabled` is defaulted to true and should partition the shuffle results according to `spark.sql.adaptive.advisoryPartitionSizeInBytes`, defaulted to 64 MB. See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html#coalescing-post-shuffle-partitions