# What's the best way to store a huge Map object populated at runtime to be reused by another tool?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, runtime

I'm writing a Scala tool that encodes ~300 JSON Schema files into files of a different format and saves them to disk. These schemas I later re-need for instantiating JSON Data files, or better, I don't need all the schemas but only a few fields of each.
I was thinking that the best solution could be to populate a Map object (while the tool encodes the schemas) containing only the info that I need. And later re-use the Map object (in another run of the tool) as already compiled and populated map.

I've got two questions:

**1.** Is this really the most performant solution? and

**2.** How can I save the Map object, created at runtime, on disk as a file that can be later built/executed with the rest of my code?

I've read several posts about serialization and storing objects, but I'm not entirely sure whether these are the same as what I need. Also, I'm not sure is the best solution and I would like to hear an opinion from people with more experience than me.

What I would like to achieve is an elegant solution that allows me to lookup values from a map generated by another tool.

The whole process of compiling/building/executing sometimes is still confusing to me, so apologies if the question is trivial.

Comment: Consider using a database.

Comment: Consider using RocksDB as KV store. It is efficient, fast, and really easy to use. You can serialize anything and put them as KV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Answer your question,

1. I think using an embedded KV Store would be more efficient considering the number of files and amount of traversal. 
   Here is a small Wiki on "How to use RocksJava". You can consider it as a KV store.  https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/RocksJava-Basics
2. You can use the below reference to serialize and de-serialize an object in Scala and put it as Key value pair in the RocksDB as I mentioned in the comment. 
   [Convert Any type in scala to Array[Byte] and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39369319/convert-any-type-in-scala-to-arraybyte-and-back/39372264#39372264)

On how to use rocksDB, the below dependency in your build will suffice: 
`"org.rocksdb" % "rocksdbjni" % "5.17.2"`

Thanks.