# How can i save Deequ Contraint Suggestions to a file for use again?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-deequ

Hi I am using Amazon Deequ to generate a set of constraints for data quality checks on my data.
I want to save the constraint suggestion object to HDS so I can load it and use it to verify any time I want to run a data quality check.
How can I save this object and re-load when needed.
this is the code I'm using to generate

```
val rules = Seq(
  CompleteIfCompleteRule(),
  RetainCompletenessRule(),
  RetainTypeRule(),
  CategoricalRangeRule(),
  FractionalCategoricalRangeRule(),
  NonNegativeNumbersRule(),
  UniqueIfApproximatelyUniqueRule()
)

// Analyse dataset and return suggestions
val suggestionResult = ConstraintSuggestionRunner()
  .onData(data)
  .addConstraintRules(rules)
  .run()

// display(suggestionResult)
val constraints = {
  suggestionResult.constraintSuggestions.flatMap {
    case (_, suggestions) => suggestions.map { _.constraint }
  }.toSeq
}
```

I want to save either constraints or suggestionResult

Answer (score 0):

It would be worthwhile to get more detail on the use-case you have in mind. Typically, persisting the constraint suggestion results and applying them to new datasets automatically is not an advisable approach (if not an anti-pattern).

Constraint suggestion results give you a good starting point to express your expectations around the data, based on profiling results. However, they should be validated by a human before enforcing them on new data. Once acknowledged, you can easily generate the necessary validation code via the `.codeForConstraint` call on an individual constraint suggestion. This makes it rather easy to assemble the necessary validation code and include it in your code base.

Persisting and reusing constraint suggestions without an intermediate human audit sounds more like an anomaly detection use case, where you are aiming to ensure that new batches of a dataset exhibit similar properties as the original input dataset that you used as reference for constraint suggestion. This use case is discussed in more detail in [the Deequ documentation](https://github.com/awslabs/deequ/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/amazon/deequ/examples/anomaly_detection_example.md).

These points being mentioned, if you really need to write and re-read the constraint suggestions, you'll need to make traits `Constraint` (and `Analyzer`) serializable (by having them extend `Serializable`). This would unblock you, but you'd need to raise an issue/submit a PR over at the [Github repository](https://github.com/awslabs/deequ). If this is accepted, you'll be able to serialize the constraint suggestions as follows, using the [serialization approach from another StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39371571/736957):

```scala
val constraints = suggestionResult.constraintSuggestions
    .flatMap {
        case (_, suggestions) => suggestions.map(_.constraint)
    }

val serializedConstraints: Array[Byte]  = serialise(constraints)
val deserializedConstrinats: Iterable[Constraint] = deserialise(serializedConstraints)
    .asInstanceOf[Iterable[Constraint]]
```